# React Native Element UI ButtonGroup Not showing on Android

Tags: android, react-native

This code below works fine on iOS but doesnt show on Android. I'm using Genymotion as the emulator.
Idea any why this would be the case?

```
    renderNext() {
      return(
        <Text>Next<Text>{this.props.next.length > 0 ? ` ${this.props.next.length}` : ""}</Text></Text>
      )
    }


       <ButtonGroup
          selectedIndex={this.state.index}
          buttons={["Past", "Current", this.renderNext()]}
          containerStyle={{height: 50, borderWidth: 0, backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 30, paddingBottom: 30, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: 'lightgray', borderRadius: 0, paddingLeft: 0, marginLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0}}
          innerBorderStyle={{width: 0, color: 'white'}}
          textStyle={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: '600', color: 'lightgray'}}
          selectedTextStyle={{color: "#4cd6a3"}}
          onPress={(selectedIndex) => this.updateIndex(selectedIndex) }
        />
```

It's supposed to show in the top part of the container.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested your code, and if I remove the **paddingBottom: 30** the buttons appear on android, maybe you could use Platform in order to determinate if it's Android or IOS and set the paddingBottom according to it.
example `Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "paddingBottom: 30" : "the padding the works or empty"`

```
       <ButtonGroup
          selectedIndex={this.state.index}
          buttons={["Past", "Current", this.renderNext()]}
          containerStyle={{height: 50, borderWidth: 0, backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 30, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: 'lightgray', borderRadius: 0, paddingLeft: 0, marginLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0}}
          innerBorderStyle={{width: 0, color: 'white'}}
          textStyle={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: '600', color: 'lightgray'}}
          selectedTextStyle={{color: "#4cd6a3"}}
          onPress={(selectedIndex) => this.updateIndex(selectedIndex) }
        />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works indeed! You're awesome. I wasn't looking at the right place apparently.

Comment: Happy to help!!